# increase the length of the <input type="text">

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am working with asp.net and its been long that i have been trying to increase the size/length of the textbox in asp.net core default web project. I tried to change the size of the textbox in html by using this code  and its is working in chrome but when i use the same format in asp.net there is no result at all. my code is (`input asp-for="Name" class="form-control`).

I tried using size,width even styles in css but the length of the textbox is same as before. I want the size form left of the screen to the right end i.e size=300.

Please help me to get it done.

Comment: you are using bootstrap, take a look here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal in order to see how to create a form in bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really good explanation about this matter for bootstrap: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp

Here you have 3 different sizes:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ex1">col-xs-2</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="ex2">col-xs-3</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for="ex3">col-xs-4</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex3" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The div class col-xs-X define the size of the input.

You can also give the input a class and in the css use !important to override the bootstrap settings:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="smallInput">
```

**CSS**

```
.smallInput {
   width: 50px !important;
}
```